# How to calculate the number of available paths from point A to B using recursion

Tags: c++

I have a programming assignment that asks to find the number of available northeastern paths from point A to point B on a grid of a maximum size of 16.

Currently I have written a program that is able to calculate one path from point A to point B but am unsure of how to calculate all of the available paths.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
const int max = 17;
const int intial = 16;
int numPath = 0;
int mover(char grid[max][max], int x, int y, int max);

int main()
{
char grid[max][max];

grid[intial][0] = 'A';
int north = 0, east = 0;
cout << "How many points north of A is B? ";
cin >> north;
cout << endl << "How many points east of A is B? ";
cin >> east;
cout << endl;

if (north > 16 && east > 16)
{
    cout << "You entered to high of a number" << endl;
    exit(1);
}
grid[intial - north][east] = 'B';
int paths = mover(grid, north, east, max);

cout << "Number of paths avaliable is " << paths << endl;
}

 int mover(char grid[max][max], int x, int y, int max)
 {


if (grid[x][y] == 'B')
{
    numPath = 1;
}
else
{
    if (x > (intial - x))
    {
        mover(grid, x - 1, y, max);
    }
    if (y > 0)
    {
        mover(grid, x, y + 1, max);
    }
}
return numPath;
}
```

Could someone help push me in the right direction?

Comment: exactly HOW is this code not working?

Comment: I need to calculate all of the available paths but my program currently only calculates one path.And I am unsure of how to get it calculate more than one path.

Answer (score 0):

I'll outline how I would get started:
Let's consider a grid of x,y where 0 <= x <= xmax and 0 <= y <= ymax.
The paths start at 0,0 (point A) and end at xmax,ymax (point B).

We want to write a recursive function pathCountTo(x,y) so that pathCountTo(xmax,ymax) will give the number of paths from A to B.

pathCountTo(0,0) = 1 because there is only one way to start at A.

There are three recursive cases, and you've already identified two.
Case 1: pathCountTo(0,y) = pathCountTo(0,y-1). (The only path to a point on the left edge is from the point directly below.)

Case 2: pathCountTo(x,0) = pathCountTo(x-1,0). (same reasoning along bottom edge).

Case 3: pathCountTo(x,y) = ?. Hint: paths can be from the left or from the bottom in this last case.